# 2つの ST s の s が同じであることを明示する方法はありますか？

Tags: haskell

次のコードにおいて型検査時に、`go = readArray array` で、その次の行のコメントのようなエラーが出ました。
エラーの原因としては、2つの `ST` の（片方は `STArray` ですが）内部状態の `s` と `s1` が別物だと認識されていることと考えています。
この `s` と `s1` が同じであると明記することはできますか？
または、この形式だと根本的に `s` と `s1` は別物になるべきでしょうか？

ちなみに `go` のシグネチャを変更したコメントアウトした版にすると `s` が同じことが明記できるので型検査が通ります。

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-9.14 --install-ghc runghc --package array

import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST

main = print $ runST $ do
    array <- newArray (0, 1 :: Int) (0 :: Int) :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
    let
        go :: Int -> ST s Int
        go = readArray array
-- starray.hs:11:14: error:
--   • No instance for (MArray (STArray s) Int (ST s1))
--     arising from a use of ‘readArray
        -- go :: STArray s Int Int -> Int -> ST s Int
        -- go = readArray
    writeArray array 1 1
    go 1
    -- go array 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(詳しい人曰く) `ScopedTypeVariables` 言語拡張を使うと良いそうです。
以下のコードで `stack runghc` したら `1` と返ってきましたよ。

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST

main :: IO ()
main = print $ runST st

st :: forall s . ST s Int
st = do
  array <- newArray (0, 1) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Int)
  let
      go :: Int -> ST s Int
      go = readArray array
  writeArray array 1 1
  go 1
```